# Почему получаю javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query после заполнения формы с помощью thyemleaf

Tags: java, hibernate

Пишу springboot приложение, использую thymeleaf, springsecurity, Entitymanager. Когда ввожу данные через форму, получаю javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query. Я совсем недавно начал изучать thymeleaf, не пойму проблема в нем или с Entitymanager.

```
    @Repository
    public class UserHibernateDAO implements UserDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<User> listAllUsers() {

   return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT distinct u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH 
   u.roles").getResultList();
   }

   @Override
   public void addUser(User user) throws SQLException {
   entityManager.persist(user);
   }

  @Override
  public void updateUser(User user) throws SQLException {

  }

  @Override
  public User getUserById(Long id) {
    Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    User user = currentSession.get(User.class, id);
    return user;

  }

  @Override
  public User findByUsername(String userName) {
    return (User) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM  User u  JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE 
  u.userName=:username", User.class)
            .setParameter("username", userName).getSingleResult();
  }


  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public class LoginController {
  @Autowired
  UserService userService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/registrationPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String homePage(User user, ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("newUser", user);
    return "registrationPage";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/registrationPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String newUserSubmit(@ModelAttribute("") User user) throws Exception {
    userService.addUser(user);
    return "redirect:/login";


  <h1>Registration Page</h1>
  <br />
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/registrationPage}" th:object="${newUser}"
      method="post">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{username}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{password}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button> </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    </body>


    @Service
    public class UserServiceImp implements UserDetailsService, UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> listAllUsers() throws SQLException {
    return userDAO.listAllUsers();
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean addUser(User user) throws Exception {
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(new Role(1L,"ADMIN"));
    roles.add(new Role(2L, "USER"));
    if(user.equals(userDAO.findByUsername(user.getUsername()))){
        return false;
    }
    if (user.getUsername().equals("") && user.getPassword().equals("")) {
        return false;
    } else
    if(user.getUsername().startsWith("admin") && 
     user.getPassword().startsWith("admin")) {

    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        userDAO.addUser(user);
    } else {
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new Role(2L, "USER")));

    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));           
        userDAO.addUser(user);
    }
    return true;
    }

     @Transactional
   public void updateUser(User user) throws SQLException {
    userDAO.updateUser(user);
     }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteUser(Long id) throws SQLException {
    userDAO.deleteUser(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public User getUserById(Long id) throws SQLException {
    return userDAO.getUserById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
     public User findUserByUserName(String userName) throws SQLException {
    return userDAO.findByUsername(userName);
    }



    @Transactional
    public boolean validate(String name, String password) throws 
    SQLException {
    return userDAO.validate(name, password);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
    UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = null;
    try {
        user = userDAO.findByUsername(username);
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }
    return user;
   }
   }

   javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1583)
com.georgyi.springbootcrud.dao.UserHibernateDAO.findByUsername(UserHibernateDAO.java:48)
com.georgyi.springbootcrud.dao.UserHibernateDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2a785f53.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
com.georgyi.springbootcrud.dao.UserHibernateDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$40d77c29.findByUsername(<generated>)
com.georgyi.springbootcrud.service.UserServiceImp.addUser(UserServiceImp.java:35)
com.georgyi.springbootcrud.service.UserServiceImp$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$80881787.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
com.georgyi.springbootcrud.service.UserServiceImp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$50d60eec.addUser(<generated>)
com.georgyi.springbootcrud.controller.LoginController.newUserSubmit(LoginController.java:30)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

Comment: Добавьте стек с ошибками для понимания что происходит, А попробуйте искать usera так  User findAllByUsername(String username);

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно,что в entity не указана аннотация @Entity. И поэтому entity Manager не может определиться

Comment: @Entity указан.